# How manually return json content in DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Here is my delegation handler

```
    public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            MyCustomClass obj = GetMyCustomObject();

            HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = GetJsonContent(obj);
            return Task.FromResult(response);

        }

        private HttpContent GetJsonContent(object obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

How could I return `obj` as a json result;

Comment: use `new StringContent(...)` and your favorit json serializer.

Comment: @DanielA.White theproblem is with StringContent the content-type of response is `text/plain; charset=utf-8` not `json`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_String_

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
response.Content = new StringContent("{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"age\":33}",
                                    Encoding.UTF8, 
                                    "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header
```